# script doesn't allow geolocation.getCurrentPosition to finish its callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation

I need to package the user's current location into an object and send it off to a PHP script.  So what I have currently is the following.

**position object**

```
function position(lat, lon) {
    this.latitude = lat;
    this.longitude = lon;

    this.setlat = function(lat) {
        this.latitude = lat;
    };

    this.setlon = function(lon) {
        this.longitude = lon;
    };

    this.print = function() {
        alert(this.longitude + ", " + this.latitude);
    };
}
```

**control flow**

```
var origin = new position(0, 0);

$(document).ready(function() {

    getLocation();
    origin.print();


});
```

**functions**

```
function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLocation, showError, {timeout:60000});
    } else {
        alert("GeoLocation is not supported on this browser or device.");
        return null;
    }

}

function setLocation(position) {
    alert('callback success!');
    origin.setlat(position.coords.latitude);
    origin.setlon(position.coords.longitude);
}

function showError(error) {
    switch(error.code) {
        case error.PERMISSION_DENIED:
            console.log("User denied the request for Geolocation.");
            break;
        case error.POSITION_UNAVAILABLE:
             console.log("Location information is unavailable.");
            break;
        case error.TIMEOUT:
             console.log("The request to get user location timed out.");
            break;
        case error.UNKNOWN_ERROR:
             console.log("An unknown error occurred.");
            break;
    }
}
```

The problem is that before the `setLocation` callback is being called, the main control flow continues and ignores the fact that I asked it get something for me.  I call getLocation and I get an alert of "0, 0" since that's what origin is originally set to.  So for some reason my `setLocation` callback just isn't getting called until everything else in the program is done.

I've looked around in the documentation, but it's rather straightforward and there isn't a whole lot going on so it's hard to pin down why this is happening.

I know a lot of people have struggled with this and there seems to be a lot of sort of 'look at this topic' but all of these topics point to code that is effectively the same as my own, but formatted a little differently.

It's important to note that I really need this position data encapsulated in a global variable since I'll be comparing my location with several dozen other locations on page-load.

**attempted solutions**
I've tried restricting my `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition()` to a while loop that exits based on the completion of the callback function, but this always results in an unending loop.

-I've tried playing with the `maximumAge` and `timeout` values in the `PositionOptions` in order to allow the function some time to finish, but again this just results in `setLocation` finishing after all other scheduled function calls are done.

-I've tried using two seperate `$(document).ready(function(){});` in order to segment the `getLocation()` and `origin.print()` functions.

-I've tried using `watchPosition` instead of `getCurrentPosition.`

Ultimately I really just need some clarification on why the callback function in `getCurrentPosition` isn't finishing until everything else does.

Comment: You should move the alert inside the callback function setLocation, inside that function you can send the object to PHP, remember javascript is Async

Comment: Unfortunately I'm kind of constrained to having a global variable since I'm comparing my location to several dozen other locations. So it doesn't quite make sense to do it that way. It really shouldn't be that hard to achieve the functionality I described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it doesn't really seem all that different from performing logic in your callback function for `getCurrentPostion` there are some technologies in Javascript which allow you to deal with asynchronicity in this way, and thus considerably clean up your code. What I'll demonstrate below is using jQuery's [`$.Deferred` object](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.deferred/) to grab your current location and package it into a variable which can be used by other functions.

```
function getLocation() {

    var deferred = $.Deferred();

    setTimeout(function() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(pos) {

            origin = new position(pos.coords.latitude, pos.coords.longitude);
            deferred.resolve();

        });

    }, 2000);
    // 2.00 seconds
    return deferred.promise();
}
```

It's important to note that we're instantiating the `origin` and resolvin the deferred object with `deferred.resolve()` in the same scope.

Now what we'll have to do is call `getLocation()` but with some added syntax to specify that the functions dealing with objects resolved inside `getLocation()` must wait until it's finished to access them.

```
getLocation().done( function() {
    origin.print();
    //do other stuff with origin
});
```

This will successfully print your coordinates, and you're free to do anything else with the data gotten by getCurrentPosition, like using Google Maps.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace this:

```
var origin = new position(0, 0);

$(document).ready(function() {

    getLocation();
    origin.print();


});
```

with this

```
var origin = new position(0, 0);

$(document).ready(function() {

    getLocation();

});

function getLocation() {

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(setLocation, showError, {timeout:60000});
    } else {
        alert("GeoLocation is not supported on this browser or device.");
        return null;
    }
}

// this is the callback
function setLocation(position) {
    alert('callback success!');
    origin.setlat(position.coords.latitude);
    origin.setlon(position.coords.longitude);
    // this is a new function that makes stuff
    processLocation();
}

// do your stuff here
function processLocation(){
    origin.print();
    // do your stuff here like comparing to other locations or sending data
    if (origin.latitude == something) blah...
}
```

Basically do your logic inside a function and call it inside the setLocation callback

Comment: While I could write the script so that ALL of my logic is done inside of this particular callback function, it strikes me as irresponsible and tough to scale.  So it's important that I'm able to make function calls after `getLocation()`

Comment: I get it, unfortunately, as far as I know, javascript by definition is asynchronous and there is no way to force the javascript call to wait until it finishes, you can change the structure on your code to make it more esthetic, but you can't get rid of the callback function

Comment: I found something called a promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise but I can't quite get it solve the problem.  I think I'm close though.